# отменить событие .hover при отведении курсора

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Подскажите пожалуйста как отменить событие `.hover` при отведении курсора? (Если убрать курсор) то все вернется на свои места.

```js
$('.mix-content li').hover(function(){
  $('.mix-content li').removeClass('is-active');
  $(this).addClass('is-active');

});
```

```css
.mix-content li.is-active {
  background-color: purple;
  color: #fff;
  }
  
.mix-content {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="mix-content">
  <li class="is-active">Текст рыбы</li>
  <li>Текст рыбы</li>
  <li>Текст рыбы</li>
  <li>Текст рыбы</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Зачем для для hover использовать js, есть же css

Comment: там в сигнатуре либо два коллбэка прописывается, один для mouseenter второе для mouseleave, либо один колбэк но через параметр можно узнать, что из них произошло. Но если ваша цель только изменить внешний вид, используйте `:hover` в стилях и все.

Comment: Можно сделать с помощью `toggleClass`, что бы не убирать, а потом добавлять класс.
Ваш пример, без особых изменений https://jsfiddle.net/w3h6j8y9/

Comment: Я понимаю, что hover можно сделать на css, в данном примере нужен js, потому-что у первого элемента есть class, который нужно убирать.

Comment: @RuslanSemenov css фичи эти вроде не все браузеры поддерживают.

Comment: @МихаилЗахаров, а чем конкретно не устраивает пример в вопросе?

Comment: @Arantler `hover` поддерживается всеми браузерами и уже давно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вроде я правильно понял...

```js
var elem = document.querySelectorAll('li');

for (let i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
  elem[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
  for (let i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
    elem[i].classList.remove('is-active');
    }
    elem[i].classList.remove('is-active');
    elem[i].classList.add('is-active');
    
  })
  elem[i].addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
  elem[i].classList.remove('is-active');
  })
}
```

```css
.mix-content li.is-active {
  background-color: purple;
  color: #fff;
}

.mix-content {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="mix-content">
  <li class="is-active">Текст рыбы</li>
  <li>Текст рыбы</li>
  <li>Текст рыбы</li>
  <li>Текст рыбы</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Зачем использовать JS, если можно сделать все на стилях?

```css
.mix-content li.is-active:hover {
  background-color: purple;
  color: #fff;
  }
  
.mix-content {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="mix-content">
  <li class="is-active">Текст рыбы</li>
  <li class="is-active">Текст рыбы</li>
  <li class="is-active">Текст рыбы</li>
  <li class="is-active">Текст рыбы</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Не одинаково, он попросил, что бы событие отменялось при отводе курсора, тоесть , что бы отменялась перекраска при отведении курсора.

Answer (score 0):

в событии hover нужно указывать1 или 2 функции

```
// 1 вариант
.hover(
  function() {
    // блок выполнится при обоих событиях
  }
);

//2 вариант
.hover(
  function() {
    // тут блок для mouseover
  }, function() {
    // а тут для mouseout
  }
);
```

функция1 (обязательный параметр) Задает функцию, код которой выполнится, когда на выбранный элемент будет наведен курсор мыши. Если в параметрах события hover Вы укажите только одну функцию ее код будет также выполнен при выводе курсора мыши за его пределы.

функция2 (необязательный параметр) Задает функцию, код которой будет выполнен, когда курсор мыши покинет пределы выбранного элемента.

в твоем случае я думаю так:

```
$('.mix-content li').hover(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('is-active');
});
```

или:

```
$('.mix-content li').hover(function(){
  $(this).addClass('is-active'); 
},
function(){
  $(this).removeClass('is-active');
}
);
```